# cURL Download latest release from github private repository

Tags: git, curl, github

I'm trying to download the latest release from a GitHub private repository. I succeeded but not the way I want it. I can download it but inside I found a folder name with my username and my latest commit id. I would like to have a different name for that folder.

I am downloading the latest release zipball:
`"zipball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/:user/:repo/zipball/v1.0.1"`

I saw that I can attach binary files to a release.

Now if I do:

`curl -H "Authorization: token :token" https://api.github.com/repos/:user/:repo/releases/latest`

I can see a a `browser_download_url` file:

`"browser_download_url": "https://github.com/:user/:repo/releases/download/:release/file.zip"`

Is there a way to do a cURL and download this file? It doesn't work the same as the above one.

Or is there a way to rename a folder inside my zip file?

Comment: you can git clone any private repo with Personal Access Token. Reff: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IJf_Tryhzic

Answer (score 1):

As of 2023, according to Github REST API documentation https://docs.github.com/en/rest/releases/assets?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-a-release-asset, the only supported Content-Type is application/json for the
`GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/releases/assets/{asset_id}`
endpoint.

It is possible to use cURL to get the file if you use curl like a regular web browser, however you need to have a valid to github.com browser sessions/cookies as HTTP headers in your request. A valid syntax should look like:

```bash
curl -O --location 'https://github.com/{USERNAME}/{REPO_NAME}/releases/download/tag/{FILENAME}.zip' \
--header 'Host:  github.com' \
--header 'User-Agent:  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:112.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/112.0' \
--header 'Accept:  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' \
--header 'Accept-Encoding:  gzip, deflate, br' \
--header 'DNT:  1' \
--header 'Sec-GPC:  1' \
--header 'Connection:  keep-alive' \
--header 'Cookie:  _gh_sess={SESSION_VALUE}; _octo=GH1.1.2006260662.1682085066; logged_in=yes; preferred_color_mode=light; tz=UTC; _device_id=c556501e17ef6ab887e37181390d27d8; user_session={SESSION_VALUE}; __Host-user_session_same_site={USESSION_VALUE}; tz=UTC; color_mode=%7B%22color_mode%22%3A%22light%22%2C%22light_theme%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22light%22%2C%22color_mode%22%3A%22light%22%7D%2C%22dark_theme%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22dark_dimmed%22%2C%22color_mode%22%3A%22dark%22%7D%7D; dotcom_user={USERNAME}; has_recent_activity=1' \
--header 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:  1' \
--header 'Sec-Fetch-Dest:  document' \
--header 'Sec-Fetch-Mode:  navigate' \
--header 'Sec-Fetch-Site:  none' \
--header 'Sec-Fetch-User:  ?1' \
--header 'Pragma:  no-cache' \
--header 'Cache-Control:  no-cache'
```

Answer (score 1):

Curl is one way to do this, [but the github-cli has some built-in features that make it a lot easier](https://cli.github.com/).

```
echo $GITHUB_TOKEN | gh auth login

# Download the Source.zip
gh release download v1.0 --archive

# Download an attachment by name or wildcard
gh release download v1.0 --pattern file.zip
```

For CURL you can also call the following API

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/releases/latest
```

and from that grab the `assets/url` or the `assets/browser_download_url` or the `zipball_url` element and then download that. You'll need to pass a auth token along the API call, since you're accessing a private repo.

```
curl -L \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>"\
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/releases/latest
```

A reply like this is returned:

```
{
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/jessehouwing/azure-pipelines-tfvc-tasks/releases/2696154",
  "assets_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/jessehouwing/azure-pipelines-tfvc-tasks/releases/2696154/assets",
  "upload_url": "https://uploads.github.com/repos/jessehouwing/azure-pipelines-tfvc-tasks/releases/2696154/assets{?name, label}",
  "assets": [
    {
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/jessehouwing/azure-pipelines-tfvc-tasks/releases/assets/1357442",
      "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/jessehouwing/azure-pipelines-tfvc-tasks/releases/download/1.1.69/jessehouwing.jessehouwing-vsts-tfvc-tasks-1.1.69.vsix"
    }
  ],
  "tarball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/jessehouwing/azure-pipelines-tfvc-tasks/tarball/1.1.69",
  "zipball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/jessehouwing/azure-pipelines-tfvc-tasks/zipball/1.1.69"
}
```

Comment: Hi, how do I download the first asset using the `browser_download_url` using curl? I can't seem to do it using personal access token.